# How can I stop running Javascript in Webkit Inspector?

Tags: webkit

Hiall, is there anyway to stop running Javascript through Webkit inspector? I am trying to debug something and I need my running code to stop.

Thanks,
Darren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You CAN pause the execution during RUNTIME, but most of the time, you won't be fast enough to stop the JavaScript where you want to.  If you want to stop the JavaScript code at a specific location, find the line you want to stop at and add a breakpoint.  This can be done by single clicking the line number of the line that you want to break on.  (You can insert multiple breakpoints)

[image]

Refresh the page, and once the JavaScript interpreter reaches this line, the browser will pause.

[image]

Once stopped at the breakpoint, you will be able to step though the code, line by line.  Once you want the JavaScript to continue executing from the current break location, simply click the PLAY button, and the page will load the rest of the way, or until a breakpoint further in the JavaScript is reached.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there should be a "Pause" button near the top right of Webkit Inspector:

[image]